@parcel/core: Failed to resolve '../homepage.html' from './src/homepage.html'
package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel src/homepage.html --open",
    "build":"parcel build src/homepage.html, src/shippng.html"

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^5.0.0",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^5.0.2",
    "parcel": "^2.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers": "^3.0.6",
    "assert": "^2.1.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "console-browserify": "^1.2.0",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "domain-browser": "^3.5.0",
    "ethers": "^6.13.1",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "marked": "^13.0.2",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "url": "^0.11.3",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "vm-browserify": "^1.1.2"
  }
}

I am trying to run a website by entering run npm dev in my terminal on Visual Studio Code, but whenever I do, the site doesn't load and I get this error:
@parcel/core: Failed to resolve '../homepage.html' from './src/homepage.html'
@parcel/resolver-default: Cannot load file '../homepage.html' in './src'.
 Did you mean './homepage.html'?
 Did you mean '../dist/homepage.html'?

Is there a way to fix this?
I have already installed npm and I have tried deleting the parcel package within the node modules folder. I was expecting the site to load, but I got similar but slightly similar errors.
